# Armazenar latitude e longitude Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou armazenando no banco de dados a latitude e a longitude. Ao retornar essa latitude ela é retornada como string. Usei o casting decimal para retornar um número com todas as casas decimais mas continua retornando como string.

```
Latitude: -21.21973152
Longitude: -47.83068889
```

Migration:

```
$table->decimal('latitude', 10, 8)->nullable();
$table->decimal('longitude', 11, 8)->nullable();
```

Model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'latitude' => 'decimal:10',
    'longitude' => 'decimal:11',
];
```

Controller:

```
public function edit(Company $company)
{
    dd(gettype($company->latitude)); //Retorna "string"

}
```

Documentação que segui: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Sobre o tipo para latitude e longitude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100163/discussion-on-question-by-marcelo-armazenar-latitude-e-longitude-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembrando que o `$casts` é opcional não é obrigatório passar você que escolhe, caso comece a comer números tente aumentar o *length* da coluna.

Migration:

```
$table->double('latitude', 10, 8)->nullable();
$table->double('longitude', 11, 8)->nullable();
```

Model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'latitude' => 'double',
    'longitude' => 'double',
];
```

Answer (score 5):

O tipo `decimal` é representado como *string*. Se você precisa dos valores em sua forma numérica, basta fazer o *cast* para esse tipo:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'latitude' => 'float',
    'longitude' => 'float',
];
```

Só tenha em mente que ao fazer isso você terá os problemas de arredondamento que naturalmente o tipo `float` possui devido às limitações de armazenamento de números. Para latitude e longitude isso não interferirá tanto - até ao ponto de nem necessitar ser `decimal` o tipo da coluna.

Você pode fazer o *cast* para `real`, `float` ou `double`.

Comment: `Float`normalmente causa problemas na exibição de latitude e longitude, removendo as casas decimais ,  não acho q vá resolver apenas trocar o tipo do cast

Comment: @ErlonCharles Mas isso é limitação do *cast* ou da exibição?

Comment: Da exibição, o cast em si funciona perfeitamente

Comment: @ErlonCharles Então a resposta atende, não? O *cast* é feito sem perder as casas decimais, a questão de truncamento deve ser levada em consideração só quando for exibir o valor, se isso for necessário.

Comment: O problema dele é na exibição e não em como salva no banco

Comment: @ErlonCharles Não, o problema é que a coluna está como `decimal` e ele estranhou obter uma *string* no PHP. Não foi citado truncamento em exibição na pergunta.

Comment: Realmente não tem na pergunta, mas ele iseriu nos comentários

Comment: @Woss Na verdade pesquisei e vi que retornaria uma string. Mas precisava converter isso para um número com todas as casas decimais que foram armazenadas. Testei como double e perdi 2 casas decimais. Testei no google maps e a localização está correta. O problema é que não sei se a perda desas casas terá problema em outras coordenadas.

Comment: @Marcelo Mas por que precisa disso como numérico? O PHP é capaz de lidar com *strings* numéricas naturalmente. E como verificou a perda das casas decimais? Isso provavelmente aconteceu apenas quando você foi exibir o valor, não ao fazer o *cast*. São problemas distintos.

Comment: @Woss Preciso que retorne como número pq estou usando em um componente Vue. Ao dar um dd($company->latitude) no Laravel percebi a perda.

Comment: @Marcelo, a pergunta principal é "os dados estão corretos no banco?"

Comment: @ErlonCharles Sim, no banco está correto, com todas as casas decimais. O problema está sendo o retorno do que está no banco.

Comment: @Marcelo Entra no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) se quiser conversar melhor. Parece que você está complicando demais o problema.

Comment: @Woss Só para fechar, eu coloquei na migration o tipo double('latitude', 10, 8) e não precisei usar o $casts do Laravel. Aparentemente está tudo ok com a exibição no mapa. O que me confundiu foi a pergunta do stackoverflow q coloquei na pergunta que falava para usar o decimal.

Comment: @Marcelo Sim, quando você utiliza double no banco o Eloquent já traz para você o valor como double no PHP. O "problema" (que não é problema) é que o tipo decimal no banco é representado como *string* no PHP e isso que te gerou confusão - e é utilizado *string* justamente para evitar as limitações dos tipos numéricos.

Answer (score -1):

De acordo com **[essas definições](https://gizmodo.uol.com.br/quao-preciso-e-um-grau-de-longitude-ou-latitude/)**, temos a seguinte descrição da precisão das casas decimais da latitude e longitude:

> **O dígito de unidade** (um grau decimal) dá a posição em até 111 quilômetros (60 milhas náuticas, ou 69 milhas). Ele nos diz em que país aproximadamente estamos.
>
> **A primeira casa decimal** vai até 11,1 km: ela diferencia a posição de uma cidade grande de uma outra cidade grande vizinha.
>
> **A segunda casa decimal** vai até 1,1 km: ela separa uma vila de outra.
>
> **A terceira casa decimal** vai até 110m: ela identifica um campo agrícola enorme ou um campus institucional.
>
> **A quarta cada decimal** vai até 11m: ela identifica uma porção de terra. É comparável à precisão comum de uma unidade de GPS sem nenhuma interferência.
>
> **A quinta casa decimal** vai até 1.1m: ela diferencia uma árvore de outra. A precisão desse nível em GPS comercial só pode ser conseguida com correção diferencial.
>
> **A sexta casa decimal** vale até 0,11 m: você pode ver a estrutura em detalhes, para projetar paisagens ou construir ruas. Ela deve ser mais do que o suficiente para monitorar movimentação de geleiras e rios. Isso só pode ser medido com GPS bem robusto.**texto em negrito**

À partir da sétima casa decimal se trata milímetros e nanômetros, sendo assim você não tem uma necessidade de mais de 6 casas para salvar e recuperar geolocalizações com uma precisão aceitável.

## Conclusão

A troca do tipo do `$casts` é realmente a melhor forma de tratar o seu problema

Dito isso, você tem duas possibilidades para conseguir trabalhar o retorno corretamente no seu `$casts`:

1. Trocar o tipo para:

```
    protected $casts = [
        'latitude' => 'float', // pode ser real, float ou double 
        'longitude' => 'float', // pode ser real, float ou double 
    ];
```

2. Ou simplesmente converta no seu *controller* para decimal usando `(decimal)$company->latitude`

A segunda possibilidade resolve o problema, mesmo sendo a menos recomendada das duas.